# Response time of flask application that uses tensorflow, grows exponentially with the number of requests

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am setting a python application using flask(0.12.2).
In this application we are using a tensorflow(1.12.0) NN.

My problem is that the more I am requesting from my API, the slower the response it gets. It looks like it is getting overloaded.

You can check my script, where I deploy my application.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from flask import Flask, jsonify,request

app =Flask(__name__)
sess = tf.Session()





parameters={
    'W1': np.array([[ 0.5211617 , -0.16149558],[ 0.87381583,  0.67057973]], dtype="float64").reshape(2,2),
    'W2': np.array([2.3268008, 2.1230187], dtype="float64").reshape(1,2),
    'b1': np.array([[-0.3840024 ],[-0.06019319]], dtype="float64").reshape(2,1),
    'b2': np.array([-4.062307], dtype="float64").reshape(1,1)
}

parameters["W1"]=tf.convert_to_tensor(parameters["W1"])
parameters["b1"] = tf.convert_to_tensor(parameters["b1"])
parameters["W2"] = tf.convert_to_tensor(parameters["W2"])
parameters["b2"] = tf.convert_to_tensor(parameters["b2"])
x = tf.placeholder("float64", [2, None])




def forward_propagation_for_predict(X):
    cur_activations = X
    cur_activations = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(parameters["W1" ], cur_activations), parameters["b1"]))
    output_activations  = tf.math.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(parameters["W2"], cur_activations), parameters["b2"]))
    return output_activations


def predict(X):
    output_activations = forward_propagation_for_predict(x)
    prediction = sess.run(output_activations, feed_dict={x: X})[0][0]
    return prediction



@app.route('/model', methods=['GET','POST'])
def serve_utils():
    result = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.json
        prediction = predict(np.array([content['x1'],content['x2']], dtype="float64").reshape(2,1))
        result['prediction']=str(prediction)[:5]
    return jsonify(result)



if __name__=="__main__":
    http_server = WSGIServer(('', 9096), app)
    http_server.serve_forever()
```

Then I am requesting from my application multiple times and I am printing out the response time, using the following code.

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://localhost:9096/model"
import datetime

def request_my_local_API(x1,x2):
    return requests.post(url, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"}, verify=False,
                  data=json.dumps({"x1":x1,"x2":x2})).json()



for i in range(2000):
    t0=datetime.datetime.now()
    prediction = request_my_local_API(i*3, i*4)
    if i%100==0:
        print('Iteration:'+str(i)+'| Time for response: '+str(datetime.datetime.now()-t0)+' | Current prediction: '+prediction['prediction'])
```

The script prints out the following:

```
Iteration:0| Time for response: 0:00:00.020178 | Current prediction: 0.016
Iteration:100| Time for response: 0:00:00.017582 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:200| Time for response: 0:00:00.024748 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:300| Time for response: 0:00:00.033445 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:400| Time for response: 0:00:00.040043 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:500| Time for response: 0:00:00.048611 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:600| Time for response: 0:00:00.102753 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:700| Time for response: 0:00:00.063461 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:800| Time for response: 0:00:00.075354 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:900| Time for response: 0:00:00.080214 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:1000| Time for response: 0:00:00.092557 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:1100| Time for response: 0:00:00.102275 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:1200| Time for response: 0:00:00.110713 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:1300| Time for response: 0:00:00.126928 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:1400| Time for response: 0:00:00.135294 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:1500| Time for response: 0:00:00.139847 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:1600| Time for response: 0:00:00.151268 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:1700| Time for response: 0:00:00.154732 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:1800| Time for response: 0:00:00.161457 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:1900| Time for response: 0:00:00.182295 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:2000| Time for response: 0:00:00.182100 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:2100| Time for response: 0:00:00.191160 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:2200| Time for response: 0:00:00.211021 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:2300| Time for response: 0:00:00.248748 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:2400| Time for response: 0:00:00.220034 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:2500| Time for response: 0:00:00.250308 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:2600| Time for response: 0:00:00.274345 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:2700| Time for response: 0:00:00.252312 | Current prediction: 1.0
Iteration:2800| Time for response: 0:00:00.314059 | Current prediction: 1.0
```

The issue is solved after I defined the operations once and only call session.run to predict values.

So I modified one line of code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from flask import Flask, jsonify,request

app =Flask(__name__)
sess = tf.Session()





parameters={
    'W1': np.array([[ 0.5211617 , -0.16149558],[ 0.87381583,  0.67057973]], dtype="float64").reshape(2,2),
    'W2': np.array([2.3268008, 2.1230187], dtype="float64").reshape(1,2),
    'b1': np.array([[-0.3840024 ],[-0.06019319]], dtype="float64").reshape(2,1),
    'b2': np.array([-4.062307], dtype="float64").reshape(1,1)
}

parameters["W1"]=tf.convert_to_tensor(parameters["W1"])
parameters["b1"] = tf.convert_to_tensor(parameters["b1"])
parameters["W2"] = tf.convert_to_tensor(parameters["W2"])
parameters["b2"] = tf.convert_to_tensor(parameters["b2"])
x = tf.placeholder("float64", [2, None])




def forward_propagation_for_predict(X):
    cur_activations = X
    cur_activations = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(parameters["W1" ], cur_activations), parameters["b1"]))
    output_activations  = tf.math.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(parameters["W2"], cur_activations), parameters["b2"]))
    return output_activations

output_activations = forward_propagation_for_predict(x)

def predict(X):

    prediction = sess.run(output_activations, feed_dict={x: X})[0][0]
    return prediction



@app.route('/model', methods=['GET','POST'])
def serve_utils():
    result = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.json
        prediction = predict(np.array([content['x1'],content['x2']], dtype="float64").reshape(2,1))
        result['prediction']=str(prediction)[:5]
    return jsonify(result)



if __name__=="__main__":
    http_server = WSGIServer(('', 9096), app)
    http_server.serve_forever()
```

Then I am requesting from my application multiple times the response time is every time almost the same!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each time you call `forward_propagation_for_predict`, new operations are added to the graph, and is causes the slowdown. The graph grows without bound and this is problematic, but also, unneeded.

You should define the operations once and only call `session.run` to predict values.